# get attributes/part of the gallery shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode, gallery, regex

I'm trying to grab all image id's that are associated with the [gallery] shortcode that are listed as exclude. For example: if my post has `[gallery exclude="1,2,3"]` I'd like to get a variable that would echo like this `echo $excludes;` result `1,2,3` thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to find a solution that worked for me, but since all I was looking for was the delimited list of attachment id's associated with a certain attribute like `exclude` or `hide`, this worked for me:

```
# Grab the list of "hide" attribute
$regex_pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match ('/'.$regex_pattern.'/s', $post->post_content, $regex_matches);
    if ($regex_matches[2] == 'gallery') :
     $attribureStr = str_replace (" ", "&", trim ($regex_matches[3]));
     $attribureStr = str_replace ('"', '', $attribureStr);
     //  Parse the attributes
      $defaults = array (
      'hide' => '1',
     );
    $attributes = wp_parse_args ($attribureStr, $defaults);
     if (isset ($attributes["hide"])) :
      $excludeID = get_post_thumbnail_id() . ',' . $attributes["hide"];
     else :
      $excludeID = get_post_thumbnail_id();
   endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 3):

## The task

It's not as easy, as it looks at a first glance. The main problem is, that you can define your own `[gallery]` shortcode and simply override the default. Actually that's what some themes are doing (blame you ThemeForest authors!). In this case, simply hooking into `post_gallery` won't work in every case.

#### Drawbacks for `post_gallery`

The problem is that both the shortcode, as well as the core callback can be overridden and therefore every callback will simply be knocked out.

#### Drawbacks for `the_content`

If you're switching to another filter and take the raw output, then you'll have to deal (another time) with the Regex. This is slow and mostly won't be simple.

So what to do now? Easy. Interact with the `global $shortcode_tags`. It holds the callback as second argument, so it's actually not too hard to determine in which case we are. Then we can simply switch on demand. This way we have a fine balance between reliability and performance.

## Build a base plugin

Here's a plugin that defines an `abstract` class (one that must get `extend`ed in order to work). There're three things that need definition in the child class:

- `$part` - the part you want to retrieve
- `$type` - the type of match you need. Valid are `digit/alphanumeric/alpha`
- `process_atts()` - the method that processes your output - whatever you want to do with the result

Just upload this via (S)FTP into your plugins folder and activate.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#70451) »kaiser« Get Gallery attributes (Base) */
if ( ! class_exists( 'wpse70451_extract_gallery_atts' ) )
{

abstract class wpse70451_extract_gallery_atts
{
    public $atts  = array();

    public $error;

    // Must get defined in extending class
    public $part;
    public $type;

    public static function init()
    {
        is_null( self :: $instance ) AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        ! isset( $this->part ) AND new WP_Error();

        add_action( 'loop_start', array( $this, 'error_handler' ) );

        // The value of the array is the callback fn name
        // If it's the default, then we're on the safe side,
        // as the core fn is no pluggable and can't get overridden.
        if ( 'gallery_shortcode' === $GLOBALS['shortcode_tags'] )
        {
            add_filter( 'post_gallery', array( $this, 'get_gallery_atts' ), 0, 2 );
        }
        // Else we have to go with a slower regex
        else
        {
            add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'get_gallery_ids' ), 0 );
        }
    }

    public function error_handler()
    {
        if (
            ! in_array(
                 $this->type
                ,array(
                     'digit'
                    ,'alphanumeric'
                    ,'alpha'
                 )
            )
            OR ! empty( $this->type )
        )
            return new WP_Error( 
                 'invalid_type'
                ,__( 'Invalid type set.', 'wpse70451_textdomain' )
                ,__FILE__
            );
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $is_error = $this->error;

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $is_error ) )
            return;

        // No error message for Guests or Subscribers
        // Assuming that no one has activated caching plugins when debugging
        // and not set WP_DEBUG to TRUE on a live site
        if ( 
            ! is_user_logged_in()
            AND ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) 
            AND ( ! defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) OR ! WP_DEBUG )
        )
            return '';

        // Error output for development
        return "{$is_error->get_error_message( 'invalid_type' )}: {$is_error->get_error_data()}";
    }

    public function get_gallery_ids( $content )
    {
        $pattern = get_shortcode_regex( $content );
        preg_match_all( "/{$pattern}/s", $content, $matches );
        $atts = explode( " ", array_shift( $matches[3] ) );
        foreach ( $atts as $att )
        {
            if ( strstr( $att, $this->part ) )
                break;
        }
        preg_match_all( $this->get_regex( $this->type ), trim( $att ), $atts );
        $this->atts = array_filter( $atts );

        return $content;
    }

    // Build pattern
    public function get_regex( $type )
    {
        switch ( $type )
        {
            case 'digit' :
                $pattern_atts = '/(\d*)/';
                break;

            case 'alphanumeric' :
                $pattern_atts = '/([A-Za-z0-9]*)/';
                break;

            case 'alpha' :
                $pattern_atts = '/([A-Za-z]*)/';
                break;

            default :
                // Add a method name `get_pattern()` to the extending class
                // to work with a custom regex pattern.
                if (  method_exists( $this, 'get_pattern' ) )
                {
                    $pattern_atts = $this->get_pattern();
                    break;
                }
                $pattern_atts = $this->get_regex( 'alphanumeric' );
                break;
        }

        return $pattern_atts;
    }

    public function get_gallery_atts( $content, $atts )
    {
        $this->atts = $atts[ $this->part ];

        // Allow overrides to trigger
        // at this point we already got what we need
        return $content;
    }

    // Must get defined in extending class
    public abstract function process_atts() {}
} // END Class

} // endif;
```

## Handle a task, get a child

Here you see the actual processing plugin. First it hooks itself statically to the `init` hook and then runs the parents `__construct()` method to retrieve the attributes.

Then you need to define what attributes you want to retrieve (see the classes properties `$part` and `$type`, which already default to what you asked for).

The last two decisions you need to make are

1. What do I want to do with my result? See `process_atts()`
2. When do you want to output the result. See `__construct()` and where `process_atts()` is hooked in.

It's as easy as that.

If you need a custom regex, just add a method named `get_regex()` to your extending class and `return` your custom pattern. Then set the `$type` to and empty string `''` and you're ready to go.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#70451) »kaiser« Get Gallery excludes */

if ( ! class_exists( 'wpse70451_extract_gallery_excludes' ) )
{
    add_action( 'init', array( 'wpse70451_extract_gallery_excludes', 'init' ) );

final class wpse70451_extract_gallery_excludes extends wpse70451_extract_gallery_atts
{
    public static $instance;

    public $part = 'exclude';

    public $type = 'digit';

    public static function init()
    {
        is_null( self :: $instance ) AND self :: $instance = new self;
        return self :: $instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent :: __construct();

        // Example hook: `loop_end`
        add_action( 'loop_end', array( $this, 'process_atts' ) );
    }

    public function process_atts()
    {
        $markup = '';
        // Do something with $this->atts;
        return print $markup;
    }
} // END Class

} // endif;
```

Alter what you need and then again: Just upload this via (S)FTP into your plugins folder and activate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What if all I wanted to do was return the list in a variable I could use in an $args array?
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'exclude'     => $myvariablehere

Comment: Just add this inside `process_atts()` in the extending class (child Plugin), exactly as I described it in the explanation.

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Properties cannot be declared abstract in /wp-content/plugins/get_gallery_attributes_base.php on line 13`

Comment: Good catch. It's not tested as I wrote both plugins off of my head - fixed. Just got no time to add a proper error handling for one of those, but this shouldn't keep you back from using it.

Comment: `$this->atts` is returning this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => ) )` and if I assign it to `$excludes` and echo it, I get nothing.

Comment: @sosukeinu Btw, did you actually fill any of the needed data in the extending child class?

Answer (score 1):

If you also need to display the content on the same page, what about using the `post_gallery` filter? You won't need any regex then

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'gallery_shortcode_excludes', 10, 2);
function gallery_shortcode_excludes($content, $attr) {
    $excludes = $attr['excludes'];
    // maybe also save it in some global/class/static variable

    //  return empty string to let wordpress continue to the shortcode output
    return '';
}
```